# Error while configuring Django with mod_wsgi on Python inside Anaconda: "ImportError: No module named django.core.wsgi"

Tags: python, django, apache, anaconda, wsgi

I'm having few problems running django+apache2 on ubuntu.
Django 1.7, Apache2.4.7

I'm running anaconda stack with 3.4 as main + another environment on python 2

I was trying to set up simple test site and received internal error 500, with below error messages in error log of Apache:

```
[Sat Jan 10 11:56:16.095032 2015] [:error] [pid 14441:tid 140015774267136] [client 127.0.0.1:59135] ImportError: No module named django.core.wsgi
[Sat Jan 10 12:03:01.895432 2015] [:error] [pid 14439:tid 140015774267136] [client 127.0.0.1:59157] mod_wsgi (pid=14439): Target WSGI script '/PATH/mysite/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Sat Jan 10 12:03:01.895483 2015] [:error] [pid 14439:tid 140015774267136] [client 127.0.0.1:59157] mod_wsgi (pid=14439): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/PATH/mysite/wsgi.py'.
[Sat Jan 10 12:03:01.895498 2015] [:error] [pid 14439:tid 140015774267136] [client 127.0.0.1:59157] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Sat Jan 10 12:03:01.895515 2015] [:error] [pid 14439:tid 140015774267136] [client 127.0.0.1:59157]   File "/PATH/mysite/wsgi.py", line 13, in <module>
[Sat Jan 10 12:03:01.895565 2015] [:error] [pid 14439:tid 140015774267136] [client 127.0.0.1:59157]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
[Sat Jan 10 12:03:01.895582 2015] [:error] [pid 14439:tid 140015774267136] [client 127.0.0.1:59157] ImportError: No module named django.core.wsgi
```

wsgi.py:

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mysite.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

its running ok with

```
python manage.py runserver
```

So the issue here is (I think) mod-wsgi wasn't configured on correct python, as default python is ("mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.6 configured") and django is installed on anaconda 2.7.9 one.

If my guess is good (please let me know what other info would we need for soultion)
My question is: how do I recompile mod-wsgi so its linked against 2.7.9 environment from anaconda?
Another question would be, can I leave it as it is and just add some directive to link to anaconda libraries? Which folder would be that and where do I put WSGIPythonHome directive then?

Thank you for having a look

Comment: Please include the contents of your mysite/wsgi.py .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had similar problem, answer was in virtual host file:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess mysite python-path=/path/to/mysite:/path/to/anaconda3/envs/python2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
WSGIProcessGroup mysite
WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py

ServerName www.mysite.com
ServerAlias mysite.com
ServerAdmin webmaster@mysite.com

<Directory /path/to/mysite/mysite>
<Files wsgi.py>
Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>

ErrorLog /path/to/web/test/error.log
```

Comment: What do you mean with "virtual host file"?

Answer (score 0):

Check this setting in `httpd.conf` of your Apache:
In your `<VirtualHost x:y>` section, make sure that value of `python-path` in `WSGIDaemonProcess` is including **the Python site-packages directory in your Anaconda installation**.
Othwerwise, mod_wsgi may not find Django that you've installed for Python ***inside Anaconda***.

For example, if you've installed Anaconda to:
`/opt/anaconda2`
Python site-packages directory may be:
`/opt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages`
Therefore, change `WSGIDaemonProcess` as:
`WSGIDaemonProcess YOUR_PROJECT_NAME python-path=/opt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages:YOUR_PROJECT_DIRECTORY ......`
(Separate each path by colon `:`)

Note:
1. **The version number within the path may change according to your tools' version.** Please find similar path and try it.
2. This issue may happen on every Linux distribution (not only Ubuntu), even Windows.

Comment: If that was required where you aren't using a Python virtual environment, it would imply you have bigger problems. Namely, it would mean your mod_wsgi is not compiled against the Anaconda Python installation and instead compiled for the system Python version. You should not use mod_wsgi compiled for one Python distro/version with files from another Python installation, or virtual environment created against different installation or version.